# 18.04 bluetooth doesn't work

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 18.04

everyone! I'm a total rookie in Ubuntu and tech in general but I've appreciated the high performance Ubuntu offers. Though, I am facing a problem. The bluetooth cannot connect with my headphones. The device is located by Ubuntu but the circle keeps spinning with no result. Meanwhile, there's a "Not set up" indication on the right. Could you please help me out? Thanks in advance.